# Entity with a list of same entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core, and I'm trying to create a Profile "follow" relation in my object, but I get an error when trying to create a migration:

Profile Entity:

```
public class Profile {

    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Profile> FollowersProfiles { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Profile> MembersProfiles { get; set; }

}
```

So when `Profile1` start to follow `Profile2`, I would have access to this relation in the `FollowingProfiles`, and when `Profile1` join the `Profile2` membership, I would have this relation in the `MembersProfiles`

When I run `dotnet ef migrations add InitialDb` I get the following error:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Profile.FollowersProfiles' of type 'ICollection'.
> Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or byusing 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

If I remove one of the `ICollection` properties, it works good.

Answer (score 0):

As your error says, you have to manually configure that relationship.

First you need to  add two extra fields to your entity:

```
public class Profile {
    ...
    public virtual Profile ParentProfile { get; set; } //to support ef-core navigation
    public int ParentProfileId { get; set; } //to be used as foreign key
    ...
}
```

Then you need to create a class like this:

```
public class ProfileConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Profile>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Profile> builder)
    {
        builder
            .HasOne(x => x.ParentProfile)
            .WithMany(x => x.FollowersProfiles)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentProfileId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade); // keep an eye on this, Choose the behavior you want
        builder
            .HasOne(x => x.ParentProfile)
            .WithMany(x => x.MembersProfiles)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentProfileId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}
```

And then you need to use that config in your context adding this

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);


        // ps: If you already have an override for this method just add the following line to it
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ProfileConfiguration());
    }
```

Comment: Cannot create a relationship between 'Profile.MembersProfiles' and 'Profile.ParentProfile', because there already is a relationship between 'Profile.FollowersProfiles' and 'Profile.ParentProfile'. Navigation properties can only participate in a single relationship.